# Use of antispambot with $curauth->email

Tags: php, functions, email, users, author-template

This is probably pretty simple, but...

I want to use the WP function **antispambot** not on 
**get_the_author_email** but on a value in a field I added to User Profile called **publicemail**. Everything I've tried throws a php error.

This is the **antispambot** usage shown in the WP docs:

```
echo antispambot(get_the_author_email());
```

And this is the complete function I'd like to get to work with **antispambot** and have it encode **publicemail**:

```
<?php
if ( !empty( $curauth->publicemail )){
echo 'Email &nbsp; <a href="mailto:' .$curauth->publicemail.' ?subject=Webmail">
<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/email_16.png"></a>'; }
?>
```

Comment: And where's the `antispambot` usage? Btw: Afaik, you should only use it on `$curauth->publicemail`, which should be the actual email.

Comment: Exactly; I only want to use `antispambot` on `$curauth->publicemail`, i.e. `antispambot($curauth->publicemail)` which doesn't work.

Comment: _What does "doesn't work" exactly mean?_

Comment: No display of an email address - either plain text or encoded -  in between the mailto: link and the ?subject=Webmail text.

Comment: wow I can't believe they included that function in the core :)

Comment: @One Trick Pony, I was surprised to see that, too. I was looking for a plain vanilla php function and WP had one.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly a good thing :) Anyway why not avoid mailto: and use [CSS](http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/07/20/ten-methods-to-obfuscate-e-mail-addresses-compared/) to trick spambots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/antispambot) states for the `antispambot()` function:

> **Return Values** *(string)* Converted email address.

You have to do one of the following:

```
echo antispambot( $curauth->publicemail );
// OR...
print antispambot( $curauth->publicemail );
```

So your full example would look like the following:

```
if ( ! empty( $curauth->publicemail ) )
{
    echo 'Email <a href="mailto:'.antispambot( $curauth->publicemail ).'?subject=Webmail">
    <img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/email_16.png"></a>'; 
}
```

#### About the difference between echo, print and (just) return

1. `echo` and `print` are just synonyms/alias for each other and actually *display* something on the screen. The only difference in usage is, that you can't use `echo` in combination with `return`.
2. `return` just gives something back as a functions output. In combination with `print`, a function can actually *display* something in a template, etc.